# How to download and play facebook videos using facebook url in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook video url. I want to download and play the video like coub app. I want to implement all this in a sample iOS project(Objective-c or swift). Please give suggestions to implement the above requirement

Thank you

Comment: Check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/video

Comment: Thank you for the reply. how can i get the video id from the video url.

Comment: I don't think you can get a video ID from a video URL. You can only do the other way round - get video URL from ID. You can get it from 'permalink_url' in the video object.

Comment: Actually i get permalink_url, source, title etc from video object by passing the video id in FBSDKGraphRequest. My problem is i don't understand how to go to that step. i.e In facebook app i copy the video link. From here onwards how to pass the video id  to the FBSDKGraphRequest is .. i don't understand. please give suggestions